# FileReader can't find XML file in the same folder

Tags: java, xml, file, reader

I am currently learning JAXP, SAX, DOM, StAX, XPath and XSLT.
And while I was testing to see how StAX works, I found myself with an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at xmltest.XMLTest.main(XMLTest.java:16)
```

It's a classic error, and I know what it means, the problem is, I don't know why is it showing up since "test.xml" and "XMLTest.java" are in the same folder/package.

Here is the code below:

***XMLTest.java -***

```
package xmltest;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class XMLTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {

        XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        Reader reader = new FileReader("test.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xmlsr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(reader);


        while (xmlsr.hasNext()) {

            switch (xmlsr.next()) {
                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                    System.out.println("START_ELEMENT");
                    System.out.println(" Qname = " + xmlsr.getName());

                    break;
                case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT:
                    System.out.println("END_ELEMENT");
                    System.out.println(" Qname = " + xmlsr.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

***test.xml -***

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2002-12-16</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
          of the world.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk103">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
          <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
          society in England, the young survivors lay the 
          foundation for a new society.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk104">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
          <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
          agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
          for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
          Ascendant.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk105">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
          <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
          battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
          Oberon's Legacy.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk106">
          <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
          <title>Lover Birds</title>
          <genre>Romance</genre>
          <price>4.95</price>
          <publish_date>2003-09-02</publish_date>
          <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
          conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk107">
          <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
          <title>Splish Splash</title>
          <genre>Romance</genre>
          <price>4.95</price>
          <publish_date>2004-11-02</publish_date>
          <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
          thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk108">
          <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
          <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
          <genre>Horror</genre>
          <price>4.95</price>
          <publish_date>2005-12-06</publish_date>
          <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
          centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk109">
          <author>Kress, Peter</author>
          <title>Paradox Lost</title>
          <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <publish_date>2006-11-02</publish_date>
          <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
          Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
          of being quantum.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk110">
          <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
          <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>36.95</price>
          <publish_date>2006-12-09</publish_date>
          <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
          detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk111">
          <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
          <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>36.95</price>
          <publish_date>2007-12-01</publish_date>
          <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
          detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
          SAX and more.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk112">
          <author>Galos, Mike</author>
          <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>49.95</price>
          <publish_date>2008-04-16</publish_date>
          <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
          looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
          integrated into a comprehensive development 
          environment.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

And here's a link to the screenshot of my hierarchy: http://pasteboard.co/6FbvgJLx6.png

Thank you in advance. :)

***EDIT***
When I put the absolute path to the file, it works perfectly, but I don't want to hard-code this...

Comment: How are you launching your program?

Comment: XMLTest.java and test.xml could be in the same directory... What of XMLTest.class?

Comment: I use Netbeans and just run the program like everything I did before...
I used a lot of FileReading, file managing etc in the past, and I don't know why is this happening now :(

Comment: Arthur, yes, XMLTest.class is in the same "classes" folder with "test.xml" :(

Comment: When running inside the Netbeans IDE, the working directory is the root of the project. If you want to access your file, use `new FileReader("xmltest/test.xml");`

Comment: Still the same output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading your file as a Resource, like this

```
URL fileURL = this.getClass().getResource("test.xml");
File file = new File(fileURL.getPath());
```

This will load your file from the same package of the class who loads the resource.

You can also provide an absolute path for your file, using

```
URL fileURL = this.getClass().getResource("/my/package/to/test.xml");
```

Comment: I cannot load the file as a resource because the URL won't import correctly for some reason...